# Canvas animation is showing all the previous frames

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to rotate an object, but all the previous frames still show up on the canvas. I think it has to do with this line:

```
setTimeout(this.rotate.bind(this), 1000 / 10);
```

How I can make it to show only the current frame?

```js
(function () {
    var spinner = {
        playerx: 810 * 0.5,
        playery: 600 * 0.75,
        shield: 1.80,
        rotation: 0,
        polyxx: [0, 12, 12, 0, -12, -12],
        polyyy: [-13.92, -5.35, 5.35, 13.92, 5.35, -5.35],
        size: 5,

        canvasInit: function () {
            this.canvas = document.getElementById('loadingScreen');
            this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        },

        rotate: function () {

            this.rotation += 0.02;
            this.shield -= 0.01;
            this.ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,' + this.shield + ')';

            this.ctx.save();
            this.ctx.translate(this.playerx, this.playery - 10);
            this.ctx.rotate(this.rotation);
            this.ctx.translate(-this.playerx, -(this.playery - 10));
            this.ctx.beginPath();
            this.ctx.lineWidth = 17;
            for (var a = 0; a < 6; a++) {
                this.ctx.lineTo(this.playerx + this.polyxx[a] * this.size, this.playery - 10 + this.polyyy[a] * this.size);
            }

            this.ctx.closePath();
            this.ctx.stroke();
            this.ctx.restore();


            this.loop();

        },

        loop: function () {
            setTimeout(this.rotate.bind(this), 1000 / 10);
        },

        init: function () {
            this.canvasInit();
            this.loop();
        }
    };
    spinner.init();
})();
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas style="background:#000;" id="loadingScreen" width="810" height="600"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear your canvas each time you animate.

Add `this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);` to the beginning of your `rotate` method to achieve this.

**For example:**

```js
(function () {
    var spinner = {
        playerx: 810 * 0.5,
        playery: 600 * 0.75,
        shield: 1.80,
        rotation: 0,
        polyxx: [0, 12, 12, 0, -12, -12],
        polyyy: [-13.92, -5.35, 5.35, 13.92, 5.35, -5.35],
        size: 5,

        canvasInit: function () {
            this.canvas = document.getElementById('loadingScreen');
            this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
        },

        rotate: function () {
            // Clear canvas here, so that we're ready to draw the next frame
            this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);

            this.rotation += 0.02;
            this.shield -= 0.01;
            this.ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(255,255,255,' + this.shield + ')';

            this.ctx.save();
            this.ctx.translate(this.playerx, this.playery - 10);
            this.ctx.rotate(this.rotation);
            this.ctx.translate(-this.playerx, -(this.playery - 10));
            this.ctx.beginPath();
            this.ctx.lineWidth = 17;
            for (var a = 0; a < 6; a++) {
                this.ctx.lineTo(this.playerx + this.polyxx[a] * this.size, this.playery - 10 + this.polyyy[a] * this.size);
            }

            this.ctx.closePath();
            this.ctx.stroke();
            this.ctx.restore();


            this.loop();

        },

        loop: function () {
            setTimeout(this.rotate.bind(this), 1000 / 10);
        },

        init: function () {
            this.canvasInit();
            this.loop();
        }
    };
    spinner.init();
})();
```

```html
<body>
    <canvas style="background:#000;" id="loadingScreen" width="810" height="600"></canvas>
</body>
```

**N.B**

You may also want to consider using `requestAnimationFrame` instead of `setTimeout` for improved animation performance.